# Nodejs express web backend behind haproxy

Tags: node.js, express, backend, haproxy

I am trying to set up a backend with nodejs and haproxy. The problem is that, when using haproxy, when you access a page, it loads, but sometimes other resources (js, css, etc) will not load (Err: Connection refused in Chrome, failed to load ... in firefox)

It seems that adding
`option http-server-close` in haproxy configuration file solves the problem, but why is this happening? As far as I am aware, nodejs supports keepalive and enqueues requests. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Please can you share more informations like haproxy -vv and your config.

Comment: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/nodejs-express-web-backend-behind-haproxy/5217